# AudioStreamer stops when switching between cellular and wifi

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audiostreamer

I'm using AudioStreamer and everything works fine, except when I switch between cellular and wifi network. It imediately stopps.

I tested it without leaving the app by switching off the wifi network, so i can proof the problem is not caused when the app is in the background.

So, did anyone have problems with AudioStreamer when switching between networks ?

cheers Simon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes sense as the network change is an interruption in data flow… Put a breakpoint in the `stop` and `pause` methods to see what is calling it.  My suspicion is that it is being called in the `handleInterruptionChangeToState` method ([line 1924](https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer/blob/master/Classes/AudioStreamer.m#L1924))

Answer (score 1):

Some time back i also had the problem with the AudioStreamer when the 4.0 background  feature was added it stops buffering as soon as the app goes in the background. It was solved because i missed the key in the info.plist :) . But it was giving me problems after that also crashes and sometimes it use to stop.

So i just used NSURLConnection to download the data and provide it to the player. It worked g8. And if it had some kind error it worked well with the below method

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication  *)application

But i think changing the network can cause problem but you can try with a sample app with NSURLConnection.